# Dyanamic web module 3.0 required java 1.6 or newer

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

In my project i got following error in Markers. I also set java 1.6 in project facets ,java compliler and buildpath but not solve this error.

[image]

Comment: Have u did clean and build after modify the project facets ,java compiler and build path?

Comment: yes dude i do also that thing but....

Comment: Is this a maven project?

Comment: yes this is maven project

Comment: With maven lesser possible issues.With only pom.xml and src folder ( no .eclipse junk) to import. You can manage all this in pom.xml as suggested by Sujit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I got this error setting java version in pom fixed my problem
In pom.xml you can set java version
you can do this by setting below properties

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

or by providing version in maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: How u concluded it a maven project?

Comment: Because of maven tag thought it is a maven project

Answer (score 0):

The error may be related to different Jre version - one you use to start eclipse and one you use to create project. Try using same JRE in both places to avoid error. When you run eclipse.exe give jdk path as well.

```
path/to/eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\pathto\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe"
```

or update eclipse.ini and update

Also, do you want it to be 3.0 or can live with 2.5? If its not need change it 2.5 and error should go away.

Comment: This problem occur during i import a project in eclipse.If i create a new project and else else at that time their is no error or problem.

Comment: When you are importing project check your java settings. Also you may have org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs under project_root/.settings in existing code which should not be. Check version there org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=x.x and org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=x.x